# How to get only those software list which are in "Programs and Features" control panel?

Tags: vbscript

This is my VBS code:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Dim strComputer, strKeyPath
Dim objReg, strSubkey, arrSubkeys
Dim Name, Version

strComputer = "."

' Registry key path of Control panel items for installed programs
strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\"

Set objReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

objReg.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys

'Enumerate registry keys.
For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
    objReg.GetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath & strSubkey, "DisplayName" , Name
    If Name <> "" Then
         WScript.Echo Name&""&","
    End If
Next

WScript.Echo "Installed Programs listed successfully through Registry using VBScript."
WScript.Quit
```

It will give all software name list. But I want only those software which are visible in *Programs and Features* in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell with [KNOWNFOLDERID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of Programs and Features.

This gives you the exact list you see on the control panel.

```vb
Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Programs = Shell.NameSpace("shell:::{7b81be6a-ce2b-4676-a29e-eb907a5126c5}")
For Each item In Programs.Items
    WScript.Echo item
Next
```

Comment: how to run it on remote machine?

Comment: @im_mangesh `CreateObject("Shell.Application", "remote-computer")`

Comment: getting error ""ActiveX component can't create object Shell.Application""

Comment: @im_mangesh Then you probably need a different solution to achive what you want on a remote computer which is not stated in the question.